# To draw Polyline in HTML5

Tags: html, svg

How to draw polyLine between three points in svg and that should be look like a curve in the image attached. I have the red dotted three points, using that is it possible to get a polyline as in image

[image]

```
enter code here
var X = (1 - t) * p0.X + t * p1.X;
var Y = (1 - t) * p0.Y + t * p1.Y;
```

I have used the above formula for calculating the points(calculated 256 points between my control points to get smooth polyline) to draw polyline using my three control points. but it doesnt work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set fill="none" on the path element, along with the appropriate stroke attributes.

Also, you shouldn't need to do any math for this: just setting the d attribute to "M" + the (space/comma separated) X and Y of the first point + "T" + the (space/comma separated) X and Y of the second and third point should be enough.

Comment: Hi bentley, thanks for ur reply, my problem got solved by setting the fill="none". But i have tried the second option, its doesnt work  polyLine = "M" + " " + (controlpoints[0].X) + " " + (controlpoints[0].Y) + " " + "S" + " " + (controlpoints[1].X) + " " + (controlpoints[1].Y) + " " + (controlpoints[2].X) + " " + (controlpoints[2].Y);

Comment: And you're then setting that to the "d" attribute of the path?

Comment: sry Bentley, i made mistake there, its working now, thanks for ur solution

Comment: If you use "T" instead of "S", yes, it will draw quadratic curves to each point.